# Why does setTimeout fire twice in Chrome, but not IE or Firefox?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Can someone tell me why the javascript function **'GenerateNewNumber'** fires twice in Chrome, but not for IE or Firefox? Using Chrome 20.0.1132.57, IE9 and Firefox 13.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/App_JScript/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('a#RandomNumber').click(function () { initiateNewNumber(); });
        });

        function initiateNewNumber() {

            setTimeout('GenerateNewNumber();', 3000);
        }

        function GenerateNewNumber() {
            var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1123);
            document.getElementById('RandomNumber').innerHTML += '<br>' + 'Random Number is ' + randomnumber;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a id="RandomNumber" href="#">Click for Random Number</a>
</body>
</html>
```

I've searched through Stackoverflow, but can't find any suggestions which will help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Been working on this all morning, and as soon as I post it I figure it out :( I needed $('a#RandomNumber').click(function () { initiateNewNumber(); return false; });

Answer (score 1):

setTimeout expects a function as first parameter:

```
setTimeout(function() { GenerateNewNumber(); }, 3000);
```

Comment: It's better to use a function, but using a string as code is supported : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout

Comment: And if all you are doing is calling a single function, you can supply it directly: `setTimeout(GenerateNewNumber, 3000);`

Comment: That's right, Dennis. I wanted to make clear that there is a function passed as parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

window.setTimeout(GenerateNewNumber, 3000);

Comment: why did somebody down vote this? This is the correct way to pass a function.